# R - extract number from string

Tags: string, r, max

I used `max(list.files(path, "my_files_v"))` to read in the latest my_files_v version.

The directory had files of:

my_files_v1, my_files_v2, ... my_files_v9

My code seemed to work perfectly fine as the script read in always the my_file_v with the highest version until I came to version _v10. From that point onwards max(list.files(..)) always detected _v9 as the max and therefore skipped _v10 and _v11 etc.

One solution would be to extract the version number from the string using substr or something like that but is there a better way of doing that? If not, does anyone know how to extract that pattern from a string as I am very poor regarding that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use:

```
max(as.integer(gsub('my_files_v', '', list.files(path, "my_files_v")))
```

assuming your files do not have extensions like you've shown.  However, so they sort properly in my file browsers, I usually name files with zero padding.  In R you can do that with `sprintf`:

```
sprintf('%03d', 1:10)
```

For what its worth, to extract the number portion of the file name you can use regular expressions and grouping:

```
gsub('my_files_v([0-9]+)\\.Rdata', '\\1', list.files(path, 'my_files_v'))
```

Comment: oh sorry. yes the files end with .RData. So the files are named for instance my_file_v1.RData